# `inotifywait` does not terminate in bash script with `-e delete_self`; but does in interactive shell

Tags: bash, inotify, inotifywait

I'm trying to write a script which restarts a `python3 -m http.server` process when a certain directory (`_site`) is deleted and then recreated.  The script is below.  There's an inotify command in the `waitdel` function which is supposed to only block until the directory is deleted.  When it is deleted, the execution goes on with a simple polling wait until the directory is created, then the server restarts, and finally we're back to waiting.

The trouble is, when `_site` is deleted, `inotifywait` never exits in the shell script, even tho the exact same command **does** exit when I run it at the very same bash prompt I run this script in, both on `DELETE` and `DELETE_SELF`.

I've verified that the correct `inotifywait` command is run, and that the server process is not blocking the execution of the script.  So, why is it not exiting in the script?

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# serve.bash --- serve content, respawn server when _site/ is deleted

# bash strict mode
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

PID=0
DIR="$PWD/_site"                # NO FOLLOWING SLASH OR BREAKS INOTIFYWAIT
PIDFILE="$PWD/.server.pid"

die () {
    echo $0: error: $@
    exit 2
}

say () {
    echo $0 \[$(date)\]: $@
}

serve () {
    cleanup
    old="$PWD"
    cd "$DIR" || die Could not cd to "$DIR"
    python3 -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1 2>&1 &
    echo $! > "$PIDFILE"
    cd "$old"
}

waitdel () {
    while true; do
        say Set up watcher for "$DIR"...
        inotifywait -e delete_self "$DIR"
        say "$DIR" deleted, restarting server...

        # Wait&poll till the directory is recreated.
        while [ ! -e "$DIR" ]; do
            sleep 0.1
        done

        serve
    done
}

cleanup () {
    if [[ ! -e "$PIDFILE" ]]; then
        return
    fi
    sync
    PID="$(cat $PIDFILE)" && rm "$PIDFILE"
    say Kill pid="$PID"...
    [ "0" = "$PID" ] || kill -9 "$PID" \
        || die Failed to kill preexisting server on pid "$PID"
}


trap cleanup SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT

if [ -e "$PIDFILE" ]; then
    if pgrep -a python3 | grep http\\.server >/dev/null; then
        trap - SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
        die Stale pidfile found at "$PIDFILE", a potentially orphaned \
            server might be running.  Please kill it before proceeding.
    else
        rm "$PIDFILE"               # remove stale pidfile when no server proc found
    fi
fi


serve

waitdel
```

Comment: I think this is too broad. Reduce the amount of code required to reproduce the issue to minimum if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @oguz ismail's suggestion, I've tried to produce a minimal version of the script that can reproduce the issue, and here it is:

```sh
DIR="$PWD/_site"
mkdir -p $DIR
old="$PWD"
cd "$DIR" || die Could not cd to "$DIR"
python3 -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1 2>&1 &      # (1)
cd "$old"
pid=$!
inotifywait -e delete_self "$DIR" &                      # (2)
sleep 1
rmdir $DIR
sleep 1
kill $pid
echo kill                                                # (3)
```

What's going on here: past the boilerplate stuff, in expression (1) we start a python http.server process whose CWD is `$DIR`. If it is not such, i.e. the CWD is `$(dirname $DIR)`, inotifywait **does** successfully terminate. In (3) we clean up the server process.  If we kill the python process, inotifywait terminates, if we don't, it doesn't.  The output from the process

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
Serving HTTP on 127.0.0.1 port 8000 (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) ...
kill
/home/g/co/gkayaalp.com/www/_site/ DELETE_SELF
```

suggests that inotifywait terminates after (3).

So inotifywait hangs because `$DIR` is busy (I guess it is because inotify works with inodes and the python process hangs on to the inode, delaying the propagation of the deletion event). A quick way then to remedy this is to watch the parent directory instead.  I modified `waitdel` as such:

```sh
waitdel () {
    while true; do
        say Set up watcher for "$DIR"...
        while inotifywait -qq -e delete "$DIR/.."; do
            if [ ! -e $DIR ]; then
                say "$DIR" deleted, restarting server...

                # Wait&poll till the directory is recreated.
                while [ ! -e "$DIR" ]; do
                    sleep 0.1
                done

                serve
            fi
        done
    done
}
```

where now it tracks DELETE events on `$DIR/..`, and on each, checks if `$DIR` is deleted.  When it is, it waits for the directory to be regenerated, and then runs `serve` which kills the existing python process and spawns a new one.